# What should I do when optimistic locking doesn't work?

Tags: rest, language-agnostic, concurrency, http

I have this following scenario:

1. A user makes a [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request to `/projects/1` and receives an [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).
2. The user makes a [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request to `/projects/1` with the ETag from step #1.
3. The user makes another PUT request to `/projects/1` with the ETag from step #1.

Normally, the second PUT request would receive a 412 response, since the ETag is now stale - the first PUT request modified the resource, so the ETag doesn't match anymore.

But what if the two PUT requests are sent at the same time (or exactly one after the other)? The first PUT request does not have time to process and update the resource before PUT #2 arrives, which causes PUT #2 to overwrite PUT #1. The whole point of [optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control#Web_usage) is for that not to happen...

Comment: Atomize your operations in business-level transactions, as Esben explains below.

Comment: What would happen if I atomized my operations using transactions? PUT #2 would not be processed until PUT #1 is fully processed?

Comment: Become a pessimist?

Comment: well this is what locking is for.

Comment: Correct, of course Put#2 should not be processed - they're supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ETag mechanism specifies only the communication protocol for optimistic locking. It's the responsibility of the application service to implement the mechanism to detect concurrent updates to enforce the optimistic lock.

In a typical application that uses a database, you'd usually do this by opening a transaction when processing a PUT request. You'd normally read the existing state of the database inside that transaction (to gain a read lock), check your Etag validity, and overwrite the data (in a way that'll cause a write conflict when there's any incompatible concurrent transaction), then commit. If you setup the transaction correctly, then one of the commits should fail because they'll both be trying to update the same data concurrently. You'll then be able to use this transaction failure to either return 412 or retry the request, if it makes sense for the application.

Comment: The way the server currently implements the mechanism to detect concurrent updates is by comparing hashes of the resource. The server also use transactions for all operations, but I’m not acquiring any locks, which might be what causes the problem. However in your example, how can there be an error in one of the commits if the transactions are using locks?  The second transaction should be pending when reading the state, until the first transaction resolves.

Comment: @maximedupre: if you are using transaction, you have some sort of locks, though it may be implicit locks (the locks are acquired automatically when you read/update fields rather than explicitly requested). The mechanism I described above can be implemented using just those implicit locking. As your other question, it depends on the database that you're using, but many modern databases uses MVCC (multi version concurrency control) to allow multiple readers and writer to work on the same fields without unnecessarily blocking each other.

Comment: Warning: in many DBMSes (PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.), the default transaction isolation level is "read committed", where your approach is *not* enough to prevent the OP's race condition. In such DMBSes, you can fix it by including `AND ETag = ...` in your `UPDATE` statement's `WHERE` clause, and checking the updated-row-count afterward. (Or by using a stricter transaction isolation level, but I don't really recommend that.)

Comment: @ruakh: it depends on how you write your query, yes the default isolation level doesn't provide such behaviour automatically for all queries, but it's often possible to structure your transaction in a way that will be sufficient to implement optimistic locking. In most cases, if transaction consistency is important in the application, I'd recommend repeatable read as default isolation level anyway; in databases that uses MVCC, the overhead of repeatable read is fairly minimal and it simplifies the application significantly.

Comment: @ruakh: the main drawback of repeatable read is that you'll have to be prepared to retry or fail if there is concurrent transaction. This is normally a problem, but applications that provides Optimistic locking as a concurrency strategy will already require this handling anyway, so repeatable read failures map naturally to optimistic locking failures and this won't actually add new drawbacks.

Answer (score 13):

You have to execute the following pair atomically:

- checking of the tag for validity (i.e. is up to date)
- updating the resource (which includes updating its tag)

Others are calling this a transaction — but fundamentally, the atomic execution of these two operations is what prevents one from overwriting the other by accident of timing; without this you have a race condition, as you're noting.

This is still considered optimistic locking, if you look at the big picture: that the resource itself is not locked by the initial read (GET) by any User or any Users who are looking at the data, whether with intent to update or not.

Some atomic behavior is necessary, but this happens within a single request (the PUT) rather than attempting to hold a lock over multiple network interactions; this is optimistic locking: the object is not locked by the GET yet still can be safely updated by PUT.

There are also many ways to achieve atomic execution of these two operations — locking the resource is not the only option; for example, a lightweight thread or object lock may suffice and depends on your application's architecture and execution context.

Comment: +1 for noting that it is being atomic that matters.  Depending on the underlying resource being updated, this can be accomplished without transactions or locking.  For instance, atomic compare-and-swap of an in-memory resource, or event-sourcing of persisted data .

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach, agreed, and thanks for calling those out.

Answer (score 1):

It's on the application developer to actually check the E-Tag and provide that logic.  It's not magic that the web server does for you because it only knows how to calculate `E-Tag` headers for static content.  So let's take your scenario above and break down how the interaction should happen.

```
GET /projects/1
```

Server receives the request, determines the E-Tag for this version of the record, returning that with the actual content.

```
200 - OK
E-Tag: "412"
Content-Type: application/json
{modified: false}
```

Since the client now has the E-Tag value, it can include that with the `PUT` request:

```
PUT /projects/1
If-Match: "412"
Content-Type: application/json
{modified: true}
```

At this point your application has to do the following:

- Verify that the E-Tag is still correct: "412" == "412" ?
- If so, make the update and calculate a new E-Tag

Send the success response.

```
204 No Content
E-Tag: "543"
```

If another request comes and attempts to perform a `PUT` similar to the request above, the second time your server code evaluates it, you are responsible to provide the error message.

- Verify the E-Tag is still correct: "412" != "543"

On failure, send the failure response.

```
412 Precondition Failed
```

This is code you actually have to write.  The E-Tag can in fact be any text (within the limits defined in the HTTP spec).  It doesn't have to be a number.  It can be a hash value as well.

Comment: This is not a standard HTTP notation you're using here. In standard compliant HTTP, you only use ETag in a response header. You never send ETag in a request header, but instead use the previously acquired ETag value in an If-Match or If-None-Match header in request headers.

Answer (score -2):

As a complement to the other answers, I will post one of the best quotes in the [ZeroMQ documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/lua:chapter2) that faithfully describes the underlying issue:

> To make utterly perfect MT programs (and I mean that literally), **we
>   don't need mutexes, locks, or any other form of inter-thread
>   communication except messages sent across ZeroMQ sockets.**
>
> By "perfect MT programs", I mean code that's easy to write and
>   understand, that works with the same design approach in any
>   programming language, and on any operating system, and that scales
>   across any number of CPUs with zero wait states and no point of
>   diminishing returns.
>
> If you've spent years learning tricks to make your MT code work at
>   all, let alone rapidly, with locks and semaphores and critical
>   sections, you will be disgusted when you realize it was all for
>   nothing. If there's one lesson we've learned from 30+ years of
>   concurrent programming, it is: just don't share state. It's like two
>   drunkards trying to share a beer. It doesn't matter if they're good
>   buddies. Sooner or later, they're going to get into a fight. And the
>   more drunkards you add to the table, the more they fight each other
>   over the beer. The tragic majority of MT applications look like
>   drunken bar fights.